# Can you tell me why I am getting error for break command

Tags: python

As I trying to use command where I will be should be able to make my virtual assistant sleep for few minute but I getting error in break what should I do

```
def run_alexa():
    command = take_command().lower()
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing' +song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        print(time)
        talk('Current time is' +time)
    elif "take a break" in command:
        talk("ok")
        break

    elif 'who is' in command:
        command = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(command, sentences=2, auto_suggest=False)
        talk("According to wikipedia")
        print(info)
        talk(info)`enter code here`
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `break` can only be used within a loop (`for`, `while`, etc)

Comment: Did you mean to `return` instead?

Comment: `break` is used to break a loop. Here you don't have any loop. If you mean that your function is called inside another loop , than there is where you want to use the break. `break` doesn't mean it will take a break and continue after

Comment: For future references, when asking about an error in the code you should also post the error message or if possible, the traceback error messages so it is easier to help. Luckily the error in your code has been found by the users in the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

This line just works in loops, such as for and while. As you are using elif Statements, the last if question isnt even asked, if one before that was true. So, the break ist really doing anything there, even if it would work.